# Reconciling these different solubility values

Tags: solubility, concentration

In a review article [1] on the solubility of CaCO$_3$(calcite), the solubility is reported to be on the order of 1 gram/litre.

Since CaCO$_3$ has a molar mass of about 100, this solubility is equivalent to $10^{-2}$ M.

The solubility product is the square of this, $K_\mathrm{sp}=10^{-4}$.

However, the solubility product of calcium carbonate (according to various sources, like Wiki) is actually $\sim 10^{-9}$ which is 5 orders of magnitude smaller.

*What am I missing?*

[1] Miller, John P. "A portion of the system calcium carbonate-carbon dioxide-water, with geological implications." American Journal of Science 250.3 (1952): 161-203.

Comment: 1 g/l is an _insanely_ high figure for CaCO3; I won't believe it even if I see it appear in glowing red letters on a wall, written by an invisible hand. But there's a catch: what I said only applies to _pure_  water. Add some acid, and you'll easily dissolve this much, and maybe a good deal more.

Comment: Perhaps the influence of carbon dioxide?

Comment: These experiments don't seem to contain any acids that would account for it. According to the literature (Plummer et al, American journal of science 278.2 (1978): 179-216) the range of pCO$_2$ might account for like 1 order of magnitude variation, not 5. I can also cite papers where pH has no more than 1 order of magnitude effect.

Comment: Reading the title of the reference gives the hint.

Comment: But what does the "CRC Handbook or Chemistry and Physics" say? Because it is the Bible for chemical and physical constants

Comment: @Poutnik Are you referring to the CO2? Because I address this in the above comment^.

Comment: @lemon Yes, I do. As presence of CO2 can raise content of calcium in water a lot, in form of carbonate hardness CaCO3 + H2O+CO2->Ca(HCO3)2. Having dissolved hundreds of miligrams of calcium in bicarbonate mineral water is common. One has to take into account equilibrium constants for CO2(g)<>CO2(aq)<>H2CO3<>HCO3-<>CO3^2-